# Where is the mistake in this proof about rationals having eventually periodic decimal expansions?

Tags: number-theory

I know that a rational number has an eventually periodic decimal expansion, and not necessarily just periodic. So what is wrong with this 'proof' that any rational number has a periodic decimal expansion:

Suppose $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ so that $x=\frac{p}{q}$ where $p,q\in\mathbb{N}$, and say $x$ has decimal expansion $x=m.d_1d_2\ldots$. Let $[x]$ denote the fractional part of $x$. So $[x]=\frac{a}{q}$ where $a\in\{1,2,\ldots,q-1\}$. Then by the pigeonhole principle, $[10^rx]=\frac{a}{q}$ for some $r\geq1$. Therefore $0.d_1d_2d_3\ldots=0.d_{r+1}d_{r+2}d_{r+3}...$ so $x=m.\overline {d_1d_2\ldots d_r}$.

Something must be wrong here because the result isn't true, but I don't know what.

Comment: Why should $[x]$ and $[10^rx]$ have the same numerator and denominator?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

"Then by the pigeonhole principle, $\{10^rx\}=\frac aq$" is a non-sequitur. The principle says that among too many pigeons, two must be in the same hole, but it does not state thet two pigoens must be in the first hole.

Answer (score 20):

Here is a thing you can always do but which people don't seem to teach: if you have a proof that you're suspicious of, you can *go through the proof with an example*. At some point, you'll write down a false statement about your example, and that's probably where the mistake is.

(Of course you can't do this if the proof is a proof by contradiction because, if the thing you're trying to prove is true, there shouldn't be any examples. This is one reason to avoid proofs by contradiction.)

Let's take a really simple example, namely $x = \frac{1}{2} = 0.500 \dots$, whose decimal expansion is clearly eventually periodic but not periodic. $[x] = \frac{1}{2}$ again. But $[10^r x] = 0$ for all $r \ge 1$. So this is where the mistake is. (As Hagen von Eitzen says, what pigeonhole will actually tell you is that there exist $0 \le r \neq s \le q$ such that $[10^r x] = [10^s x]$. It does not guarantee that either $r$ or $s$ is equal to $0$, but there's a second mistake here: you also aren't guaranteed that this fractional part will be nonzero!)

Comment: You are wrong with the rant against proofs by contradiction (which is not the same as a proof using the excluded middle, which indeed has drawbacks). With a dubious direct proof and a counterexample (as mentioned in the first paragraph) you can test statements made in the proof against the counterexample; since the hypotheses are verified but the conclusion is not, there must be a truth->falsity transition somewhere. Now for a dubious proof by contradiction + counterexample, the hypothesis (the conclusion is false) _is verified_, the conclusion (absurdity) is not. **It is precisely the same.**

Comment: $\ldots\,$and sometimes one should go through the proof with an _extreme_ example.  Lewis Caroll wrote a purported proof in geometry accompanied by an illustration, and the conclusion was absurd, and he challenged the reader to find the error.  Everybody knows that these sorts of things have something wrong with the illustration.  At one point in the picture two lines met at a very small angle.  I modified the picture to make it a right angle and went through the whole thing and the error became obvious. $\qquad$

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen How does a [proof by contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction) not use the [excluded middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle)? It is essentially: "Theorem: P is true. Proof: Suppose P is false. [...inferences...] which is absurd. *Contradiction*. Thus P is true (there is no third option)."

Comment: @RosieF What you describe is a proof by excluded middle, also called double negation elimination, which indeed uses the excluded middle (basically "not P is absurd, so not not P, so P"). However "proof by contradiction" also (and more often) refers to a simpler  form called negation introduction. "Theorem: not P (for instance $\sqrt2$ is not rational). Proof: assume P, then (reason, reason) absurdity. So P is false, and we have proven: not P".

Comment: ... For both cases of proof by contradiction however, counterexamples **can** help to analyse incorrect proofs (and that was the point of my initial comment). For the excluded middle case, the counterexample makes your hypothesis "not P" valid, and the reasoning that deduces an absurdity from it must necessarily at some point draw an invalid conclusion from a valid assumption; this is the point where the purported proof is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Just verify the 'proof' step by step on some counterexample, say $x=\tfrac 16$, and you'll see the flaw yourself:

it's not true, that multiplying $\tfrac 16$ by a power of $10$ makes $\left[10^r\,\cdot\,\tfrac 16 \right] = \left[\tfrac 16 \right]$,

because RHS is $0.1666\ldots = \tfrac 16$ while LHS is $0.666\ldots = \tfrac 23$ for each $r\in \Bbb N^+$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take $a_r=q[10^rx]$, and just take only the case $0\le r<q$. You have at most $q$ values of $a_r$, with $0\le a_r<q$. There are two possibilities, either there are $q$ distinct values, which means that for some $r$, $a_r=0$,
or by pigeon principles there are two distinct $r$, $0<r_1<r_2<q$ such that $a_{r_1}=a_{r_2}$.

In the first case, $0=d_r=d_{r+1}=d_{r+2}=\cdots =d_{r+n}$, meaning that there is a finite expansion or the period is $0$.

In the second case, let $s=r_2-r_1$, then $d_n=d_{n+ks}$ for any $n\ge r_1$, which means that it is periodic and the period is $s$ (or a divisor of $s$).

However, $r_1$ is not necessarily $0$, as your proof presupposes.

**Nota bene:** If you don't want two cases, you can choose $q+1$ values of $r$ by making $0\le r\le q$.

**Nota bene 2:** We have proven that the period $p$ is always lesser than $q$. Actually we can define the function $e$,
$$\begin{array}{rcl}e:\mathbb N&\to&\mathbb N\\q&\mapsto&e(q) \end{array}$$
such as $e(q)$ is the number of values $r$, $0\le r<q$, such as $r$ and $q$ are relative prime: $\operatorname{GCD}(r,q)=1$. We can prove that $e(q)<q$ (for any $q>1$). And furthermore, we can prove that the period $s$ of any fraction $\frac pq$ is a divisor of $e(q)$ (including $e(q)$ itself).

**Nota bene 3:** The conclussion in your proof holds whenever $\operatorname{GCD}(q,10)=1$, this means for any odd denominator which is not divisible by $5$. You have probably noticed that your proof fails at $\frac12,\frac14,\frac15,\frac16,\frac18,\frac1{10},\frac1{12},\frac1{14},\frac1{15},\ldots$
A good excersise: figure out why, and then predict how many decimal digits before it becomes periodic.